# 3D plot in Matlab With Two Axis in X and Y

Tags: matlab

I have two functions, lets say L(t,w) and K(m,n). I want to visualize these two planes in the same cordinates. The intersection of these planes gives me the answers (m0,n0,t0,w0).

I could plot these planes using the following code:

```
[nL,mL] = meshgrid(linspace(min(n),max(n),max(Nn,Nt)),linspace(min(m),max(m),max(Nm,Nw)));
[tL,wL] = meshgrid(linspace(min(t),max(t),max(Nn,Nt)),linspace(min(w),max(w),max(Nm,Nw)));

[nM,mM] = meshgrid(n,m);
[tM,wM] = meshgrid(t,w);

Kint = interp2(nM,mM, K, nL, mL);
Lint = interp2(tM,wM, L, tL, wL);

figure;

surface(tL,wL,Lint, 'FaceColor', [0.1 0.1 1], 'EdgeColor', 'none');
surface(tL,wL,Kint, 'FaceColor', [0.1 1 0.1], 'EdgeColor', 'none');

grid;

view(3); camlight; axis vis3d;
```

while the x and y axis have different representation, is there any way which i can put an axis with values of n in parallel to t and one with values of m in parallel to w?

It should be doable and easy.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/graph-with-multiple-x-axes-and-y-axes.html)

This should also work in 3D. Use the axes command to create a new axis and put it in a different position and then use 'Parent', youraxes when calling surface the second time.

Comment: Please add more.  Link-only answers are discouraged as we don't know when the link will expire.

Comment: No, it is not working like this, it is not 3D anymore